# Change path /comment/reply/11#comment-form

Tags: comments

How I can change path from ***/comment/reply/11#comment-form*** to ***/node/$node->nid/#comment-form*** in node $links?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Do you want the path to get to the comment form to be `/node/nid/#comment-form` instead of `/comment/reply/cid#comment-form`? I don't think just changing the path in the link is going to still get you to the comment form.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is a Drupal 6 issue:

The Comment module create the links with [hook_links()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_links/6). You can alter those in a custom module using [hook_links_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_link_alter/6).

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7, you can add something like this to your template.php:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
  // Update 'reply' link to make it go to the comment form page anchor instead of some weird comment post page
  if (isset($vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply'])) {
    $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']['href'] = url('node/' . $vars['node']->nid, array('fragment' => 'comment-form', 'absolute' => TRUE));
  }
}
```